# ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0

Tags: flutter, maps, google-places-api

This is my Code in AssistantMethods.dart

```
class AssistantMethods
{
  static Future<String> searchCoordinateAddress(Position position, context) async
  {
    String placeAddress = "";
    String st1, st2, st3, st4;
    String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json? 
latlng=${position.latitude},${position.longitude}&key=$mapKey";
    print(position.latitude);
    print(position.longitude);

    var response = await RequestAssistant.getRequest(url);
    print(response);
    if(response != "failed")
    {
      //placeAddress = response["results"][0]["formatted_address"];
      st1 = placeAddress = response["results"][0]["address_components"][0]["long_name"];
      st2 = placeAddress = response["results"][0]["address_components"][1]["long_name"];
      st3 = placeAddress = response["results"][0]["address_components"][2]["long_name"];
      st4 = placeAddress = response["results"][0]["address_components"][3]["long_name"];
      placeAddress = st1 + ", " + st2 + ", " + st3 + ", " + st4;

      Address userPickUpAddress = new Address();
      userPickUpAddress.longitude = position.longitude;
      userPickUpAddress.latitude = position.latitude;
      userPickUpAddress.placeName = placeAddress;

      Provider.of<AppData>(context, listen: false).updatePickUpLocationAddress(userPickUpAddress);
    }

    return placeAddress;
  }

  static Future<DirectionDetails> obtainPlaceDirectionDetails(LatLng initialPosition, LatLng 
finalPosition) async
  {
    String directionUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?
```

origin=${initialPosition.latitude},${initialPosition.longitude}&destination=${finalPosition.latitude},
${finalPosition.longitude}&key=$mapKey";

```
    var res = await RequestAssistant.getRequest(directionUrl);

    if(res == "failed")
    {
      return null;
    }

    DirectionDetails directionDetails = DirectionDetails();

    directionDetails.encodedPoints = res["routes"][0]["overview_polyline"]["points"];

    directionDetails.distanceText = res["routes"][0]["legs"][0]["distance"]["text"];
    directionDetails.distanceValue = res["routes"][0]["legs"][0]["distance"]["value"];

    directionDetails.durationText = res["routes"][0]["legs"][0]["duration"]["text"];
    directionDetails.durationValue = res["routes"][0]["legs"][0]["duration"]["value"];

    return directionDetails;

  }
}
```

This is my Code in MainScreen.dart:

```
  Future<void> getPlaceDirection() async
  {
    var initialPos = Provider.of<AppData>(context, listen: false).pickUpLocation;
    var finalPos = Provider.of<AppData>(context, listen: false).dropOffLocation;

    var pickUpLatLng = LatLng(initialPos.latitude, initialPos.longitude);
    var dropOffLatLng = LatLng(finalPos.latitude, finalPos.longitude);

    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) => ProgressDialog(message: "Please wait...",)
    );

    var details = await AssistantMethods.obtainPlaceDirectionDetails(pickUpLatLng, dropOffLatLng);

    Navigator.pop(context);

    print("This is Encoded Points ::");
    print(details.encodedPoints);
  }
}
```

Here is a part of my error log:
..............................................................................
I/flutter (26872): This is your Address ::Guillamac's Bldg., Carlos P.
Garcia Avenue, Tagbilaran City, Bohol
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(26872): beginBatchEdit on inactive
InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(26872): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive
InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(26872): getTextAfterCursor on inactive
InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(26872): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(26872): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(26872): beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(26872): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
I/Choreographer(26872): Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too
much work on its main
thread.
W/Looper  (26872): Slow Looper main: doFrame is 614ms late because of 1 msg
I/flutter (26872): This is Drop Off Location ::
I/flutter (26872): BQ Mall
W/Looper  (26872): Slow Looper main: doFrame is 472ms late because of 1 msg
E/flutter (26872): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled
Exception: RangeError
(index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0
E/flutter (26872): #0      List.[] (dart:core-
patch/growable_array.dart:254:60)
E/flutter (26872): #1      AssistantMethods.obtainPlaceDirectionDetails
(package:rider_app/Assistants/assistantMethods.dart:58:51)
E/flutter (26872): 
E/flutter (26872): #2      _MainScreenState.getPlaceDirection `enter code  here`(package:rider_app/AllScreens/mainscreen.dart:294:19)
E/flutter (26872): 
E/flutter (26872): #3      _MainScreenState.build.
(package:rider_app/AllScreens/mainscreen.dart:202:27)
E/flutter (26872): 
E/flutter (26872):

Answer (score 1):

This error signifying , you are calling those index which does not exist, here your error clearly saying that your list is empty, and you are calling value at it's index, you should check list length before calling it's index.

I do not know in which list you are getting this error.
but answering for all 4 list which i figured out from your code.

```
print(response);
   if(response != "failed")
   {
     var length:response["results"].length;
     print("NUMBERS OF RESULTS:$length");
     if(length > 0){ //check length for result list
        if( response["results"][0]["address_components"] > 0){ //this for address_components list 
      //Perform your code here

          

         }
      
      }
       
 
      }
```

OR

```
var length:res["routes"].length;
print("NUMBERS OF ROUTES:$length");

if(length > 0){ //check length for route list
  if(res["routes"][0]["legs"].length > 0){ //check length for legs list
      //perform your code here
   }
 
 }
```

Comment: I already found the solution, i must diabled the apiKey restrictions, change to no restrictions in the settings in tge google maps platform api key restrictions.

Comment: how to do that @NinYu ... disable the api key restrictions for directions api ?

Comment: @Ali Yar Khan yes!