# Has google maps changed something ? my app was working 2 days ago but now not wroking

Tags: android, flutter, google-maps, dart, geolocation

[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67014713/errorflutter-lib-ui-ui-dart-state-cc186-unhandled-exception-rangeerror-ind/68237347?noredirect=1#comment120600119_68237347)

i coded the same app in this  linked question codes are the same and problem is the same but..untill 2 days ago it was working well and now its not working..i checked the advice in answers about apiKeys but my Api restrictions are all "None" already.do you have any idea about how to solve this problem ?

Comment: This error refers to trying to access an array through an index that doesn't exist, eg your array only goes up to 3 and you try to access position 4. In the code you linked, the json coming from google maps are deserialized to a combination of maps and arrays, as you said two days ago it was working and now it isn't, what happens is that depending on where you are and what you are searching on Google maps the detail of the coming json can change and this can do how your array size is affected.

Comment: first of all Thanks for the answer.I know it s a size problem actually but 2 days ago it was working during 4 mounths.there was no any error..now from the same location the same code the same device all the same conditions..but started not to receive the addres :( this is so annoying

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.When i started to use geocoding api i had created a billing account.although i gave my credit card informations they started a free trial account and now it s expired that s why it wasnt working...i just activated it and problem solved...google had to warn by mail or etc in this kind of situations.